# UITableViewCell content moves when cell is reused

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, prepareforreuse

I have a custom UITableViewCell with some content defined in a xib with nested stack views. Some views are added in code to the stackViews so each cell may have different height.

When moving away from the tableview (ie. push/pop another ViewController and scrolling back to the first cell (which was not visible when leaving the view) the content is moved down (see picture) and does not completely fit in the cell. What is the cause of that?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Please add some relative code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Common cause is adding new subviews without clearing out the previous ones. That's the first place I'd look. If you don't see that happening, post some of your code or, best, a reproducible example.

Comment: Seems that the problem was caused by calls to tableView.beginUpdates(), *showSomeLabel()*, tableView.endUpdates() which caused a new cell to be created for the same indexpath of the reused cell. Removing the animation solved the problem.